# Cloud Run, ideal vCPU and memory amount per instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

When setting up a cloud run, I am worried about how many memory and vCPU should be set each time per server instance.

I use Cloud Run for mobile apps.

I am confused about when to increase vCPU and memory instead of increasing server instances, and when to increase server instances instead of vCPU and memory.

How should I calculate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a good answer to that question. You have to know the limits:

- The max number of concurrent requests that you can handle concurrently with 4cpu or/and 32Gb of memory (up to 1000 concurrent requests)
- The max number on instance on Cloud Run (1000)

Then it's a matter of tradeoff, and it's highly dependent of your use case.

- Bigger instances reduce the number of cold starts (and so high latency when your service scale up). But, if you have only 1 request at a time, you will pay a BIG instance for a small processing
- Smaller instances allow you to optimize cost and to add only a small slice of resource in your cluster, but you will have to spawn often a new instance and  you will have several cold start to endure.

Optimize what you prefer, find the right balance. No magic formula!!

Comment: If cold start doesn't matter at all, it sounds good to use vCPU 4 and Memory 32GB unconditionally then

Comment: no, if cold start doesn't matter, you don't care to create frequently a new instance and in that case I recommend you to have a smaller instance. Imagine, you can process 20 concurrent requests per CPU on your instance. You have 85 requests; If you use a 4vCPU instance, you will need 2 instances (80 requests handle on the first one, and 5 on the second one), so 8 vCPU to pay. If you have 1vCPU instance, you will need 5 instances, so 5vCPU to pay. Personally, I will choose smaller instances.

Comment: So then I don't choose 5 server instances of 512mib memory, vCPU1, maximum requests 200 (by the way, wasn't the server instance automatically increased? Is it different from when I set it to 1000 and when I set the maximum to 80? Hm Perhaps by changing the max limit, it's the difference between making a more waiting choice or increasing the server instance, I think.) And I'll set the vCPU4 and memory 32GB Maximum requests per container to 200 just to use one server instance. And Lastly (I should set maximum instances to maybe 1-2? ) Does it sound good?

Comment: But there will be a cold start right? (When the second instance is newly allocated)  As I understand it, if you set the maximum server instances small, cold start and waiting time for a response will increase if there are many users. Even for a really big job, if the number of users is small, it would be better to reduce the server instance and increase the memory and vCPU. And even for a really small task, if the number of users is overwhelming, it would be better to just make the server instance very large. Do I understand correctly

Comment: Hmm.. if I want to do a large-scale service, but in my case Cloud Run is the server for rest api. Hmmm, I don't think it's high-level memory work, but 32GB of memory is a bit of a luxury, isn't it? maybe.. If I dare to guess, wouldn't it be better to raise the instance max to 500 with 16 GB of memory and 4 vCPUs? Yes I know the exact answer is very difficult. But when you think about it, and I know it's really abstract and personal, but I'd love to hear what you think is average. My head is blowing because of this.. hwoo.. so difficult. Sorry for the vague question, just feel comfortably.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a load of requests in your current settings using [k6.io](https://k6.io), check the memory and cpu percentage of your container and adjust them to a lower or higher setting to see if you can get more RPS out of a single container.

Once you are satisfied with a single container instance's let's say 100 rps per container instance, you can then specify using `gcloud` the flags `--min-instances` and `--max-instances` depending of course on the `--concurrency` flag, which in my explanation would be set to 100.

Also note that it starts at the default of 80 and can go up to 1000.

More info about this can be read on the links below:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy

I would also recommend you investigating if you need to pass the `--cpu-throttling` flag or the `--no-cpu-throttling` depending on your need for adjusting for cold starts.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on how adjusting the CPU throttling flag helps with cold starts? Which option helps reduce cold starts and what are the downsides? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, sorry for the delay on the answer, but essentially, while throttling (default behavior) when there is no use, your container sorts of sleeps. Passing the --no-cpu-throttling avoids that, but also costs more, as CPU is always allocated.

This article highlights it very well: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-gets-always-on-cpu-allocation